# Passing variables from awk to PHP

Tags: php, awk

I am trying to pass back the results/variables from the awk command (called from PHP) back to the PHP script for further manipulation. Following is my script:

```
$cmd = "/usr/bin/awk '{if($1 >= \"$S_Date\" && $1 <= \"$E_Date\"){sum+=$5; row+=1}} END{avg=sum/row;print avg}' data.txt";
$avg = system($cmd);
echo "Avg: $avg\n";
```

where, `$S_Date` and `$E_Date` are PHP variables. I can get the avg from awk returned in the `$avg` var but, have the following issues.

Issues:

1. I want to avoid echoing the avg to the stdout too, from the awk command itself?
2. How to return/store multiple variables from the awk command, say both sum and avg?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) instead.
The second parameter allows you "catch" the output of the command.

```
exec($cmd_to_run, $output);
```

**Note:** If you just need the last line, `$last = exec($cmd_to_run);` will suffice.

Comment: it seems to store all the vars from awk in all the indices of the array $output. i.e., $output[0]=$output[1]=..= val1 val2. So, do I need to extract individual value from the index OR can I have each  output in a separate index? Thanks.

Comment: If you pass the second parameter, each line of output from the command is placed as a string into the array.  If you just need the final (last line) output, you don't need the second parameter.
For your situation, the last line should be enough.